# Markov umbrellas

Tags: probability, markov-chains

"I have $4$ umbrellas randomly distributed between my house and my office. Each day I go from my house to the office and back. If it's raining, i will take an umbrella in my way to the other place. If it isn't raining, i won't take any umbrella. It could happen that I'm in a place with $0$ umbrellas and it started raining, so I would get wet. The rain probability (in each decision-making moment) is $p\in(0,1)$. What is the probability $P_W$ of getting wet in the long run (infinite days)?

I have modelled a Markov chain with states $\Omega=\{M,0,1,2,3,4\}$, where $M$ is the state of being wet, $0$ of being in a place with $0$ umbrellas, $1$ of being in a place with $1$ umbrella, etc.

For instance, if I am in a place with $3$ umbrellas, I will take an umbrella with probability $p$ to the other place, adding up $2$ umbrellas in the new place (the umbrella that was there and the one that I have used). I won't take an umbrella with probability $1-p$, adding up $1$ umbrella in the new place (the one that was there). And so on.

[image]

I have calculated the hitting probabilities of $M$ starting from each state. Let $H_i$ denote the hitting probability of $M$ starting from the state $i$. By the Law of total probability:

$H_M=1 \\
H_0=pH_M + (1-p)H_4 \\
H_1=pH_4 + (1-p)H_3 \\
H_2=pH_3 + (1-p)H_2 \\
H_3=pH_2 + (1-p)H_1 \\
H_4=pH_1 + (1-p)H_2 \\
$

The solution of this system is $H_M=H_0=H_1=H_2=H_3=H_4=1$.

Applying again the Law of total probability:

$P_W = 0H_M+\frac{1}{16}H_0+\frac{1}{4}H_1+\frac{3}{8}H_2+\frac{1}{4}H_3+\frac{1}{16}H_4 = 1$

But I have been told that the solution is not $1$ (is dependent of $p$ and the number of umbrellas). What I have done wrong?

Comment: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/725334/professor-has-4-umbrellas-markov-chain-and-probability) is similar.

Comment: Should add:  I agree with your conclusion unless degenerate cases are allowed (you appear to exclude them by saying $p\in (0,1)$).  If $p=0$ then of course you can't get wet.  If $p=1$ then you won't get wet unless you happen to start in the state with no umbrellas (and the probability of that clearly depends on the number of umbrellas).

Comment: Note:  It is not true that the probability of starting in each state is $\frac 15$.  At least, I'd have said that the assumption that the umbrellas were "randomly distributed" meant that each umbrella had an equal chance of starting in either place.  Of course, this does not alter the conclusion in the case $0<p<1$.

Comment: You are right, my mistake. I'm gone to fix it. But as you have said, it doesn't matter because you're pondering 1.

Comment: It matters in the degenerate case $p=1$.

Comment: Yes, but as yoou have said, I'm not considering it. I think that I have fixed it.

Comment: Maybe the probability of getting wet doesn't mean getting **ever** wet but the fraction of days when you get wet.

Comment: ploosu2, I think that you are right. The way the problem has been written seems a little bit ambiguous and your interpretation seems very reasonable. Thank you :D!

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are at home and going to office. There can be 5 states either you have 01234 Umbrellas at home. There are four events possible :
(rain rain) ; (Rain, no rain) ; (no rain, rain) ; (no rain,no rain).

you can construct a probability transition matrix in the case of each of these events starting from every state. Then you can calculate the steady state probabilities of All the five states.Then,

P(wet) = s0 * P(rain),

Since the case going from office to home is symmetrical and the probability of being at office or being at home initially is equal the final answer is the above expression only.

upon calculation I found that (s1 = s2 = s3 = s4 = 1/(q + 4)) and
s0 = (q/(q + 4)) .  Where q = 1- p.